# Client Computer cannot connect to mssql server 2008 using odbc

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc

[This is the error when connecting to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz8iY.png)

Please help. When connecting to sql server using odbc.

Comment: Don't link to images containing vital information, it does future users of this site no good when the link breaks; also, the text of the error message won't come up in searches.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to a SQL Server instance that is running on a server that is in a different Windows domain than the client.  Either the domains need to trust each other, or you need to login using SQL Server authentication instead of Windows authentication.